# Taylor Series centered at 2 Question

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

I need a little bit of assistance with the following problem:

Calculate general Taylor Series and the first 3 terms of the Taylor series centered at 2 of the
function

f(x) = ln(x^2 + 2x + 1)

I know the first step would be calculating multiple derivatives as below:

f'(x)=2/(x+1)

f"(x)= -2/(x+1)^2

f"'(x)=4/(x+1)^3

f""(x)= -12/(x+1)^4

f""'(x)=48/(x+1)^5

What would be the next step after doing this? I guess my issue is turning this into a taylor series using the formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Since $f(x)=\log\bigl((x+1)^2\bigr)=2\log(x+1)$, then$$f'(x)=\frac2{x+1}=\frac2{3+(x-2)}=\frac23\cdot\frac1{1+\frac{x-2}3}.$$

Comment: where did you get the 3 from? and how would you turn this into a taylor series?

Comment: The $3$ comes from the difference between $x+1$ and $x-2$. And$$\frac1{1+\frac{x-2}3}=1-\frac{x-2}3+\frac{(x-2)^2}{3^2}-\frac{(x-2)^3}{3^3}+\cdots$$

Comment: and how does this turn into a taylor series?

Comment: Since $f'(x)$ is the sum of that power series and since $f(2)=\log9$, then$$f(x)=\log9+2(x-2)-\frac{2(x-2)^2}{2\times3}+\frac{2(x-2)^3}{3\times3^2}-\frac{2(x-2)^4}{4\times3^3}+\cdots$$

Comment: I thought there were factorials in the problem. would the denominator be (n+1)*3^!?

Comment: No, but I made a mistake. The answer is:$$f(x)=\log9+\frac23(x-2)-\frac{2(x-2)^2}{2\times3^2}+\frac{2(x-2)^3}{3\times3^3}-\frac{2(x-2)^4}{4\times3^4}+\cdots$$

Comment: @EmilyRichards i.e $$f(x)=2\ln{(3)}+\frac23\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}(x-2)^k}{k\cdot3^{k-1}}$$

Comment: @PeterForeman I think that it is more natural to write it as$$2\log(3)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}(x-2)^k}{k\times3^k}.$$

Comment: @PeterForeman wouldnt it have to be multiplied by (x-2)^n because its centered at a=2?

Comment: The summation index doesn't matter. The $(x-2)^n$ terms are given instead by $(x-2)^k$ terms in the expansion I gave.